# Java serial port configure gnu.io.rxtx.properties window

Tags: java, serial-port

I am trying to run this function and I get configure gnu.io.rxtx.properties window with text:
gnu.io.rxtx.properties has not been detected.

There is no consistant means of detecting ports on this operating System.  It is necessary to indicate which ports are valid on this system before proper port enumeration can happen.  Please check the ports that are valid on this system and select Save.
When I click save on command window appears text:

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts

but program still doesn't work.

```
   public void connect(String serial){
              this.serialPort = null;
              try {
                      CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(serial);
                      if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
                              System.out.println("Port in use!");
                      } else {
                              System.out.println(portIdentifier.getName());

                              this.serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open(
                                              "ListPortClass", 300);
                              int b = this.serialPort.getBaudRate();
                              System.out.println(Integer.toString(b));
                              this.serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                              SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                             // serialPort.setInputBufferSize(65536);
                             // serialPort.setOutputBufferSize(4096);

                              System.out.println("Opened " + portIdentifier.getName());

                              OutputStream mOutputToPort = this.serialPort.getOutputStream();
                              InputStream mInputFromPort = this.serialPort.getInputStream();
                              this.OutputToPort = mOutputToPort;
                              this.InputFromPort = mInputFromPort;
                              this.connected = true;
                      }
              } catch (IOException ex) {
                      System.out.println("IOException : " + ex.getMessage());
              } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException ex) {
                      System.out.println("UnsupportedCommOperationException : " + ex.getMessage());
              } catch (NoSuchPortException ex) {
                      System.out.println("NoSuchPortException : " + ex.getMessage());
              } catch (PortInUseException ex) {
                      System.out.println("PortInUseException : " + ex.getMessage());}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same error on Linux, and it turned out to be a permission problem. After adding the user account to the "uucp" group (as described on http://rxtx.qbang.org), make sure to log out and log in again on the system.

Answer (score -1):

I have met the same problem and I solved it after searching other's method. The IDE which I use is Eclipse, the other IDE's solution should be similar.

The error is due to Run Configuration, we just need to change the former RXTX.gun.io's Main Class to your program's Main Class.

Run > Run Configure > Main Class > Search